# Iterate over Eventbrite API response to assign key value pairs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, loops, eventbrite

Good morning StackOverflow,

I am a coding student working with React and am having an issue with using the Eventbrite API.  I have logged the data that I want to get back from the JSON API response, but now I want to write a function that will create key value pairs of the name of the data and the values.  I know it is possible to assign these pairs, however I am not finding a good way to achieve this in my searching.

Here is my code that I am working with:

```
 export default class Cards extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      cards: {}
    }
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get(`https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.latitude=25.8014116&location.longitude=-80.1990871&location.within=25km&expand=venue,category&token={apitoken}`).then(({data}) => {
      this.setState({cards: data})
      console.log({data}.data.events[0].name.text)
      console.log({data}.data.events[0].start.local)
      console.log({data}.data.events[0].end.local)
      console.log({data}.data.events[0].venue.address.localized_address_display)
      console.log({data}.data.events[0].description.text)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  makeCards = () => {
    const cardEvent = this.state.cards.events
      cardEvent.map((event, name) => {
        return (
        <div>
          <p>Event Name: {this.state.cards.events.event.name}</p>
        </div>
      )})
  }  
}
```

The makeCards function is the one I am trying to write.

Here is an example of what the API object returns:

```
{
"pagination": {
    "object_count": 4134,
    "page_number": 1,
    "page_size": 50,
    "page_count": 83,
    "has_more_items": true
},
"events": [
    {
        "name": {
            "text": "Wynwood Life 2019: Art / Music / Food / Fashion",
            "html": "Wynwood Life 2019: Art / Music / Food / Fashion"
        },
        "description": {
            "text": "\nExperience ALL of Wynwood in ONE weekend! \nWynwood Life is back again for 2019 and will be looking to unite and celebrate the heart of Wynwood through the best local experiences of ART. FOOD. FASHION. DRINKS. MUSIC.\nThis free three-day festival in partnership with SWARM and the Wynwood Bid will feature Wynwood's best of...\n\nART: Must over Art installations from around the globe and world-renown muralist paintingsThe ART OF WAR is a mural battle between 2 incredible teams to determine the best muralist team in Wynwood. This is a yearly competition curated by Creative Glue to highlight the best artist in Miami. Each team is comprised of 3 members all with different artistic styles merge into one team to create a custom 12x8ft Mural. Each will have 2 hours to complete their masterpiece and for the world to see. The crowd, not judges, will decide the winner and a champion will be crowned. Enjoy sounds by DJ Uzo, Revolution Radio and a Muscle Car show activation as the teams battle for the ART OF WAR.\n\n\nFOOD: Indulge in gourmet food from Wynwood's mouth-watering local food businesses, a Food Truck Rally, and the Kitchen Lab with Wynwood's Finest, mixing up your favorite cuisine!\nDRINKS: Curated unique cocktails at thedeck, and your favorite specialty brews from Wynwood's best local Breweries and Restaurants at the Beer Garden  \nSouth Florida’s very best Wynwood-based chefs will be showcased at THE KITCHEN LAB with Wynwood’s favorite local breweries to refresh the palette at the Wynwood Beer Garden adjacent to thedeck Wynwood for specialty cocktails sponsored by Espolon Tequila, Absoult, Jack Daniels, and Sip Smith Gin.\n\n\n\nACTIVATIONS: Partake in one-of-a-kind blow your mind sponsor activations\nMUSIC: Expand your musical interests with Wynwood's most eclectic mix of talented Dj's on our live music stages,\nSHOPPING /FASHION: Peruse through Wynwood's beautiful mix of local businesses and our curated Thrifter Market with local vendors displaying creative and unique products \n\nWe look forward to bringing to life the Wynwood culture and allowing those near and far, young and old, to participate in a truly memorable weekend. \nSWARM takes pride in being the innovative trend-starters when it comes to South Florida events and Wynwood Life is sure to encompass just that, with featured partners from iHeart’s Y-100, 103.5 93.9 MIA, and TU94.9\nSchedule: FRIDAY: 4pm - 3am / SATURDAY: 12pm - 3am / SUNDAY: 12pm - 10pm\nRegister for your Free Welcome Drink with RSVP! (First 500 guests to arrive)\nVENDORS: To apply for your spot with us, please visit www.thrifter.coolor call us at 305-239-8833.\nSponsors: Interested in partnering with us or setting up an activation at our event? Please email partners@swarminc.com. \nMust be 21+ to consume alcohol.\n",
            "html": "<P CLASS=\"p1\"><SPAN CLASS=\"s1\"><BR></SPAN></P>\n<P><SPAN><STRONG>Experience ALL of Wynwood in ONE weekend!</STRONG> </SPAN></P>\n<P>Wynwood Life is back again for 2019 and will be looking to unite and celebrate the heart of Wynwood through the best local experiences of ART. FOOD. FASHION. DRINKS. MUSIC.</P>\n<P>This free three-day festival in partnership with SWARM and the Wynwood Bid will feature Wynwood's best of...</P>\n<UL>\n<LI>ART: Must over Art installations from around the globe and world-renown muralist paintings<BR><BR>The ART OF WAR is a mural battle between 2 incredible teams to determine the best muralist team in Wynwood. This is a yearly competition curated by Creative Glue to highlight the best artist in Miami. Each team is comprised of 3 members all with different artistic styles merge into one team to create a custom 12x8ft Mural. Each will have 2 hours to complete their masterpiece and for the world to see. The crowd, not judges, will decide the winner and a champion will be crowned. Enjoy sounds by DJ Uzo, Revolution Radio and a Muscle Car show activation as the teams battle for the ART OF WAR.</LI>\n</UL>\n<UL>\n<LI>FOOD: Indulge in gourmet food from Wynwood's mouth-watering local food businesses, a Food Truck Rally, and the Kitchen Lab with Wynwood's Finest, mixing up your favorite cuisine!</LI>\n<LI>DRINKS: Curated unique cocktails at thedeck, and your favorite specialty brews from Wynwood's best local Breweries and Restaurants at the Beer Garden  <BR>\n<P>South Florida’s very best Wynwood-based chefs will be showcased at THE KITCHEN LAB with Wynwood’s favorite local breweries to refresh the palette at the Wynwood Beer Garden adjacent to thedeck Wynwood for specialty cocktails sponsored by Espolon Tequila, Absoult, Jack Daniels, and Sip Smith Gin.</P>\n</LI>\n</UL>\n<UL>\n<LI>ACTIVATIONS: Partake in one-of-a-kind blow your mind sponsor activations</LI>\n<LI>MUSIC: Expand your musical interests with Wynwood's most eclectic mix of talented Dj's on our live music stages,</LI>\n<LI>SHOPPING /FASHION: Peruse through Wynwood's beautiful mix of local businesses and our curated Thrifter Market with local vendors displaying creative and unique products </LI>\n</UL>\n<P>We look forward to bringing to life the Wynwood culture and allowing those near and far, young and old, to participate in a truly memorable weekend. </P>\n<P>SWARM takes pride in being the innovative trend-starters when it comes to South Florida events and Wynwood Life is sure to encompass just that, with featured partners from iHeart’s Y-100, 103.5 93.9 MIA, and TU94.9</P>\n<P><STRONG>Schedule: </STRONG>FRIDAY: 4pm - 3am / SATURDAY: 12pm - 3am / SUNDAY: 12pm - 10pm</P>\n<P>Register for your <STRONG>Free Welcome Drink</STRONG> with RSVP! (First 500 guests to arrive)</P>\n<P>VENDORS: To apply for your spot with us, please visit <A HREF=\"http://www.thrifter.cool/\" TARGET=\"_blank\" TITLE=\"thrifter.cool\" REL=\"nofollow noopener noreferrer\">www.thrifter.cool</A>or call us at 305-239-8833.</P>\n<P><SPAN>Sponsors: Interested in partnering with us or setting up an activation at our event? Please email partners@swarminc.com. </SPAN></P>\n<P>Must be 21+ to consume alcohol.</P>\n<P><BR></P>"
        },
        "id": "46885450645",
        "url": "https://www.eventbrite.com/e/wynwood-life-2019-art-music-food-fashion-tickets-46885450645?aff=ebapi",
        "vanity_url": "https://wynwoodlife2019.eventbrite.com",
        "start": {
            "timezone": "America/New_York",
            "local": "2019-01-25T16:00:00",
            "utc": "2019-01-25T21:00:00Z"
        },
        "end": {
            "timezone": "America/New_York",
            "local": "2019-01-27T22:00:00",
            "utc": "2019-01-28T03:00:00Z"
        },
        "organization_id": "184586633563",
        "created": "2018-06-08T15:34:34Z",
        "changed": "2019-01-26T00:01:43Z",
        "capacity": null,
        "capacity_is_custom": null,
        "status": "started",
        "currency": "USD",
        "listed": true,
        "shareable": true,
        "online_event": false,
        "tx_time_limit": 480,
        "hide_start_date": false,
        "hide_end_date": false,
        "locale": "en_US",
        "is_locked": false,
        "privacy_setting": "unlocked",
        "is_series": false,
        "is_series_parent": false,
        "is_reserved_seating": false,
        "show_pick_a_seat": false,
        "show_seatmap_thumbnail": false,
        "show_colors_in_seatmap_thumbnail": false,
        "source": "create_2.0",
        "is_free": true,
        "version": "3.0.0",
        "logo_id": "54738459",
        "organizer_id": "11192435431",
        "venue_id": "28662946",
        "category_id": "113",
        "subcategory_id": null,
        "format_id": "11",
        "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/46885450645/",
        "is_externally_ticketed": false,
        "category": {
            "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/113/",
            "id": "113",
            "name": "Community & Culture",
            "name_localized": "Community & Culture",
            "short_name": "Community",
            "short_name_localized": "Community"
        },
        "venue": {
            "address": {
                "address_1": "2250 NW",
                "address_2": null,
                "city": "Miami",
                "region": "FL",
                "postal_code": "33127",
                "country": "US",
                "latitude": "25.7989654",
                "longitude": "-80.19614580000001",
                "localized_address_display": "2250 NW, Miami, FL 33127",
                "localized_area_display": "Miami, FL",
                "localized_multi_line_address_display": [
                    "2250 NW",
                    "Miami, FL 33127"
                ]
            },
            "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/venues/28662946/",
            "id": "28662946",
            "age_restriction": null,
            "capacity": null,
            "name": "The Wynwood Marketplace",
            "latitude": "25.7989654",
            "longitude": "-80.19614580000001"
        },
        "logo": {
            "crop_mask": {
                "top_left": {
                    "x": 0,
                    "y": 0
                },
                "width": 2160,
                "height": 1080
            },
            "original": {
                "url": "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F54738459%2F184586633563%2F1%2Foriginal.20190107-182831?auto=compress&s=f79344d814eacca11bf975d22df04d85",
                "width": 2160,
                "height": 1080
            },
            "id": "54738459",
            "url": "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F54738459%2F184586633563%2F1%2Foriginal.20190107-182831?h=200&w=450&auto=compress&rect=0%2C0%2C2160%2C1080&s=3eb070852326c71eb337efd0bc481934",
            "aspect_ratio": "2",
            "edge_color": "#e3ccd0",
            "edge_color_set": true
        }
    }
```

The array "events" has 49 objects in it that I am trying to iterate over.

Update:  I am getting a little bit closer to what I would like to accomplish, but now I am having an issue with props/state that I cannot seem to identify.  My errors are varying degrees of "cannot identify name type of undefined" or "cannot identify events type of undefined".  Here is the updated code I am working with:

CardsList.jsx

```
> import React from 'react'
import { Grid, Card } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Cards from '../bundles/Cards/components/Cards'

const CardsList = props => {
  return (
    <Grid columns='equal' centered>
      {props.cards.map((eventcard, index) => {
  return <Cards key={index} eventcard={eventcard} />
  })}
  </Grid>
 )
}   

export default CardsList
```

and here is Cards.jsx

```
> import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Grid, Card } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import CardsList from '../bundles/CardsList/components/CardsList'

export default class Cards extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      cards: {}
    }
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get(`https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.latitude=25.8014116&location.longitude=-80.1990871&location.within=25km&expand=venue,category&token={apitoken}`).then(({data}) => {
      this.setState({cards: data})
      console.log(this.state.cards.events[0].name.text)
      console.log(this.state.cards.events[0].start.local)
      console.log(this.state.cards.events[0].end.local)
      console.log(this.state.cards.events[0].venue.address.localized_address_display)
      console.log(this.state.cards.events[0].description.text)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <p>Map coordinates</p>
            <button className="submitbutton" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Submit</button>
            <button className="submitbutton" onClick={CardsList}>MakeCards</button>
            <p>{this.state.cards["name"]}</p>
          </div>
          <div>
          <Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Row>
        <Card>
          <Card.Content>
            <Card.Header>Card</Card.Header>
            <Card.Meta>
              <span>{this.props.name}</span><br/>
            </Card.Meta>
            <Card.Description>{this.props.cards}</Card.Description>
          </Card.Content>
        </Card>
          </Grid.Row>
        </Grid.Column>
        </div>
      </div>    
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't the key value pairs already assigned?

Comment: So what I am trying to do is be able to extract that data I mentioned to render on semantic-ui-react cards.  I would like to be able to write the function so that I can use it to send props to the react cards.  Am I making sense?  I feel like what I am trying to do is hard to explain.

Comment: can you post the desired output data you want to achieve

Comment: @rmbeavin I am still not clear as to what you are asking. As gopigorantala said, please let us know exactly what you want the output to look like. What obstacles are you encountering when trying to achieve that output?

Comment: I would like the output to look something like

      props.name = this.state.cards.events[i].name.text
     props.starttime = this.state.cards.events[i].start.local
      props.endtime = this.state.cards.events[i].end.local
      props.location =     this.state.cards.events[i].venue.address.localized_address_display
      props.description = this.state.cards.events[i].description.text

Where i=the array index for 1-49.

Comment: Can you give the exact errors you are getting and what lines of code are generating those errors. Is it possible you are trying to read from state before it has been saved?

Comment: I am sorry if I missed this in your code but I don't see where you are pulling out the JSON response for iteration. For Example: then(response => response.json()) is what I used in some vanilla JS I wrote.